# Show I open my activity inside the onReceive of BroadcastReceiver when received a Push Notification

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

When using Android Push notification, the `onReceive` of the registered `BroadcastReceiver` is being called when the device receive the notification.

The issue is should I open my activity immediately inside the method `onReceive`? Because sometimes the app might be closed, so forcing open the `activity` when receiving the notification seems rude, right?

Are there any best practice for this?

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it is rude to open an activity as soon as you recieve a push, since user might be in the middle of doing something important.

The best practice is to post a [Status notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) which on clicking should take it to the activity which is relevant to the push message.